# WCF Data Service and Silverlight: DataServiceQuery<T> will not re-perform query

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

Using Silverlight 4, Oracle 11g, and Entity Framework 4.

I use a DataServiceQuery to fill a DataGrid.  Then, some local (non-EF) code updates the DB.  I would like to use the same query to refresh the DataGrid with the updated/new data.  The problem is, when I do that, it returns the old, original results.  I have verified that the changes have, in fact, been committed to the DB prior to this code running:

```
DataServiceContext<T> dsContext= new DataServiceContext<T>(uri);
dsContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
dsContext.SaveChangesDefaultOptions = SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate;
DataServiceQuery<T> dsQuery = dsContext.CreateQuery<T>(typeof(T).Name);
// oldQuery is an IQueryable<T>
dsQuery = (DataServiceQuery<T>)oldQuery;

var dsQuery = (DataServiceQuery<T>)oldQuery;
dsQuery.BeginExecute(new AsyncCallback(c =>
   {
      IEnumerable<T> result = dsQuery.EndExecute(c);
      listSelectedRecord = new List<T>();
      listSelectedRecord = result.ToList();
   }), dsQuery);
```

As far as I can tell, the new `dsQuery` is not even being sent to the Oracle server, even though a new `DataServiceContext` is being created.  It is apparently discovering that it has a cached copy somewhere.  If I type the query into a browser, it returns the updated results.

Any suggestions on how to force the DS to reperform the query?

Comment: Relevant link:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1363040.aspx/1  I was already using the MergeOption.NoTracking flag as seen above.

Comment: I've also noticed that if I look at dsContext.Entities, this DataServiceContext object doesn't seem to be tracking any entities at all!  Is the Silverlight data service client different from the .NET full version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The astonishing answers to this question seem to be found here:

[Does Silverlight cache web service calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857379/does-silverlight-cache-web-service-calls)

and

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/340931/silverlight-webclient-does-not-download-updated-resources

There seems to be be some sort of vague consensus that SLx does indeed rely on the *browser* cache, not that you would know that from the `DataService`, `DataServiceContext`, or `DataServiceQuery` docs.

**So the easiest fix for this, in IE 8 at least, is to turn off browser caching.**

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `oldQuery` to the newly instantiated `dsQuery` object apparently copies cached results from somewhere.  The solution I used here was to replace

```
 dsQuery = (DataServiceQuery<T>)oldQuery;
```

with

```
dsQuery = (DataServiceQuery<T>)(dsQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(oldQuery.Expression));
```

I would still like to understand exactly where, why, and how these results are being cached.  The `DataServiceQuery<T>` docs don't say anything about this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646574(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to be working anymore...  still open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you have any cache in the middle like htmlcache or appfabric cache?

Comment: No, but just to be sure, I've set SetNoServerCaching in the DataService OnStartProcessingRequest.  I've monitored the WCF service directly, and as I stated, I see no evidence that request is even going to the server, much less getting a cached result back from it.

Comment: Were you able to debug the code and see if the execution process does indeed hit the query loaded? (sorry trying to see any obvious issues, I am sure you have already did that.)

Comment: Yes, it does hit the query and executes the callback.  I have been checking the results of this by looking at the variable listSelectedRecord, so it clearly executes BeginExecute.  What does not happen, though, is a call to the data service.

Comment: Do you mean specifically to call `.Clear()` rather than `new List<>`?  Doesn't the latter effectively include the former?

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting your .suo file if you see this behavior when debugging.