# How to add/edit DataServiceQuery LINQ Projections in Silverlight?

Tags: linq, asynchronous, wcf-data-services, silverlight-5.0

Silverlight 5 / WCF Data Services 5.6.0 / Entity Framework 5 / Asynchronous LINQ DataServiceQuery

How can I reset/delete/uncache/remove the projections from my DataServiceQuery LINQ query in subsequent executions ?

Consider the below code:

```
var query =
    (
      from c in context.Customers
      select new Customers()
      {
          ID = c.ID,
          Name = c.Name,
      }
    ) as DataServiceQuery<Customers>;


query.BeginExecute((result) =>
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        // process results from query...
        // query.EndExecute(result).ToList();

    }), null);
```

In the above snippet, I'm creating a LINQ query with two projections (columns) which will return the ID and Name fields via WCF Data Services. This works fine; issue starts below...

In another method which executes later, I have a similar query to fetch additional columns/projections. However, the below LINQ query returns the same resultset as above and ignores the additional columns:

```
var query =
    (
      from c in context.Customers
      select new Customers()
      {
          ID = c.ID,
          Name = c.Name,
          Age = c.Age,        // additional columns returning null
          Height = c.Height   // additional columns returning null

      }
    ) as DataServiceQuery<Customers>;


query.BeginExecute((result) =>
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        // process results from query...
        // query.EndExecute(result).ToList();

    }), null);
```

Removing all projections to return all columns fails too; I just get back the initial ID and Name fields specified earlier:

```
var query =
    (
      // No projections, just get ALL columns please!

      from c in context.Customers
      select c                        
    ) as DataServiceQuery<Customers>; 


query.BeginExecute((result) =>
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        // process results from query...
        // query.EndExecute(result).ToList();

    }), null);
```

How can I get the DataServiceQuery object to discard the previously specified projections? I don't have the option to execute the query which returns all columns first.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved: Before executing any LINQ query, set the below MergeOption on the WCF Data Service context:

```
context.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

Related info:

1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/f36d2643-661e-4048-88cf-a38df36a0b1a/linq-expand-and-dataservicequery
2. [WCF Data Service and Silverlight: DataServiceQuery<T> will not re-perform query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355232/wcf-data-service-and-silverlight-dataservicequeryt-will-not-re-perform-query)