# ServiceStack: Are "GET" results cached by default?

Tags: servicestack

I am running into issue that my second GET request after POST does not get executed at all but returns results prior to POST. I cannot see the request being issued in fiddler at all. If I restart the application then it returns the correct results. I do not have any caching set up. Routes are configured like this:

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<ComplianceService>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);

Routes.Add<CertificateDefinitionList>("/certificates","GET");
Routes.Add<CertificateDefinition>("/certificates/{CertificateDefinitionId}", "GET");
Routes.Add<CertificateDefinitionSave>("/certificates","POST");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **implicit** Caching in ServiceStack. If you want to Cache responses you need to explicitly request it as [seen on the Caching wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching#cache-a-response-of-a-service):

```
public object Get(CachedOrders request)
{
    var cacheKey = "unique_key_for_this_request";
    return RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache,cacheKey, () => 
        {
            //Delegate is executed if item doesn't exist in cache 
            //Any response DTO returned here will be cached automatically
        });
}
```

Comment: Then there is something else going on as all GET requests are being cached. This is in Silverlight application.

Comment: Silverlight is the culprit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857379/does-silverlight-cache-web-service-calls

Comment: Just to be clear here, the caching is happening in the client's HTTP cache, not on the server side.

Comment: Is it possible to move caching up into a RequestFilter?

Comment: @JonCanning how, it needs to be able to execute it?

Comment: Could a RequestFilter return the response when it exists in the cache, and a ResponseFilter cache it when it doesn't?

Comment: @JonCanning sure, but then you have to rehydrate it into that cache key?  that's what the caching pattern does in 1 LOC.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by your proxy which caches results locally. Caching is enabled on http get by default. Specify http caching in your http headers.